# Node - How to run sets of tasks asynchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, gulp

I want to run a few set of tasks.

Visual representation

Set 1 - Task 1, Task 2, Task 3

Set 2 - Task 1, Task 2, Task 3

Set 3 - Task 1, Task 2, Task 3

I want to run Set 1, 2 and 3 **ASYNC** and the tasks can be **SYNC**

I also want to run a function when all sets are finished.

The way I'm trying to do it right now is

```
exec('task 1', {cwd: cwd}, function (done) {
    exec('task 2', {cwd: cwd}, function (done) {
        exec('task 3', {cwd: cwd}, function (done) {
            // do stuff after task 3
        });
    });
});
```

This is being done in a gulpfile just to give you a little bit more context.

My current problem is that I can't run the last part (after all sets are finished).

How can I solve my predicament?

Comment: Hmmm, is this your exact gulp code? I just use the basic `gulp.task('name', function() { return gulp.pipe(task1).pipe(task2).pipe(task3); };` You could also maybe create an empty gulp task with ['task1', 'task2', 'task3'] dependencies.

Comment: No. this is not my entire gulp code. I'm actually executing commands in other folders. I have other gulp tasks mixed in.

Comment: You could try piping the tasks after eachother instead of using nested callbacks. I assume you've checked that task 3 actually completes and that that isn't the problem?

Comment: yup. My problem is figuring out when all the sets are done. Imagine a for loop. but it's all async and you must run a function at the end of all sets

Comment: What about creating a gulp task that has the 3 sets as dependencies: `gulp.task('allSetsDone', ['set1Name', 'set2name', 'set3Name'], function() { //stuff to do when all sets are completed }); Then instead of running the sets seperately, run this task. It will run the other 3 sets first and after that the code in the task.